# Loop is stopping prematurely

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to integrate some code into a live file. It was working in the test file I had it in; but when I try to run it against the live data it stops after hiding one line.

No error or anything; it's just like it doesn't loop how it is supposed to. I'm not sure what the deal is.

Here is the code

```
        With tbl
        'Search ColJ ("CNC Begins") for the first cell with a color index of 15 and the ColK ("CNC Ends") which has an index color of anything other than 15
        Set colStartDate = .ListColumns("CNC Begins").DataBodyRange

        For Each c In colStartDate.Cells
            If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 And c.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> 15 And IsDate(c.Value) And Not c.Offset(0, -9).Value = "C" Then
                FoundDate = c.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c

        For Each c In colStartDate.Cells
            If Not c.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
                'Hide dates prior to colStartDate but not empty cells
                If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) And IsDate(c.Value) Then
                    MsgBox c.Value & ">=" & FoundDate & " | Address " & c.Address
                    'Exit Sub

                    If Not c.Value >= FoundDate And IsDate(c.Value) And Not IsError(c.Value) Then
                        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Caption = "Show"
```

Comment: What happens when you step through with F8?

Comment: usually when hiding/deleting rows you need to go from bottom up..

Comment: @alowflyingpig - not when hiding rows, and it's actually better to not delete rows in a loop anyway (but that's not the case here).

Comment: Chances are one of your `If` statement  has faulty criteria. Assuming you have the right range defined, you may be looping through each row but finding the criteria to jump into the `If` statement is never being met. You have not given us much to go on though